# Simple regex word question

Tags: c#, regex

I have the regex:

```
TheComment = Regex.Replace(TheComment, "(\\@" + r + "\b)", "<span style=\"background:yellow;font-weight:bold;\">@" + ThisUser.Username + "</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is an example pattern

```
(\\@to\b)
```

I want this to match `@To` but **not** `@Tom`.  At the moment it's not matching, if I strip the `\b` away it works but it matches `@Tom` as well which is musn't.

Comment: @Mark I think I need the word boundary to stop `@to` matching `@Tom`

Comment: Never mind, I think I just can't understand your question. I don't understand the purpose of those "\\" at the start, or the purpose  of the parentheses.

Comment: @TomGullen - can you explain your reasoning for each part of the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `\` and not `@`. Plus, you got to move `\b` out of the selection.

```
@"(@" + r + @")\b"
```